# Can I rely on this SQL shortcut to save a query?

Tags: mysql, optimization

Consider a table with a `status` field that holds one of two values:

```
| status | set('active','default') | YES  |  | active |
```

I need to know how many records are in the table, and additionally how many have the `status` set to `active`. I notice that `SUM` returns `1` for each record set to `active` and `2` for each record set to `default`:

```
mysql> select count(*), sum(status) from users;
+----------+-------------+
| count(*) | sum(status) |
+----------+-------------+
|        3 |           4 |
+----------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select status from users;
+---------+
| status  |
+---------+
| default |
| active  |
| active  |
+---------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Can I rely on this behaviour?** Is this a bad practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer to self!

A better way to perform the query in the OP in a single query would be to **explicitly group by status**:

```
mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) AS total, status FROM users GROUP BY status;
+-------+---------+
| total | status  |
+-------+---------+
|     2 | active  |
|     1 | default |
+-------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

In addition to being **clearer as to intention**, this solution also works for the case in which `status` has more than two possible values.

Comment: teh MySQL `GROUP BY` is a monster.  Your answer shows the standards-compliant way of performing aggregates in a query and is the only way you should be doing it.